# How and why does an electrometer measure the potential differences?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, voltage, capacitance

It was written in my school physics book that because any conductor surface is equipotential, if we have the two plates of a conductor and if we connect them to an electroscope then the change of potential between electroscope corpus and stem will equal the change potential between conductors. But I can not understand it.

Suppose let's say it is right that if we increase the positive charge plate charge then the potential change will not change because it is equal to:

$\dfrac{kQ}{r}$ and change $q$ does not change the potential. But in my opinion in the real world if we increase $q$ then it must affect the electroscope arrow.

Also, how can I calculate the potential difference between two plates? I mean, it is easy to calculate from Ed1 - Ed2 (here d1 = 0 and d2 is the distance between plates). So it becomes U = -Ed2. But how can I do this using $\dfrac{kQ}{r}$? And also why does equipotential surface cause that the change of potential between the electroscope corpus and stem are the same as the plates?

Comment: Your first long sentence is very confusing (at least to me).

Answer (score 8):

The electroscope is a capacitor, cap, stem leaf, etc., and an outer body which is earthed.

When charge is added to the cap, etc., the presence of charge is indicated by the deflection of the leaf and hence a potential difference between the cap, etc. and the outer body.

Increasing the charge, increases the deflection and so the electroscope measures the potential difference.

Note that although the simple type of leaf/vane electroscope often has a linear scale to help measure the deflection of the leaf, the voltage scale is non-linear and can easily be calibrated using a high voltage power supply.

Answer (score 5):

The  formula potential $\frac{kQ}{r}$ only applies to potential of a point charge at r=0 or a charged sphere with radius < r.What you call conductor seems to be a plate capacitor . When you connect the two sides to the electroscope, some charges go to it, so the potential changes a little bit, but if the dimensions of the electroscope are much smaller than your capacitor, this is only a small error.

Answer (score 3):

Because only potential differences can be attributed to a physically meaningful quantity according to gauge invariance. The local value of the potential can not be associated with any observable.